# How does zenity use options for radiolist?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, user-interface, zenity

I am reading [linux command line and shell scripting bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111898384X), and they use `zenity` for radiolist in this form:

```
zenity --list --radiolist --title "Sys Admin Menu" 
--column "Select" --column "Menu Item" 
FALSE "Display diskspace" FALSE "Display users" FALSE "Display memory usage" FALSE "Exit" 
> $temp2
```

1. I did not find any example in manpage, and there is no explanation in the book either, but why is before *every* option `FALSE` in the command? I have tried to remove it, but then the option would not display correctly. (there would be just few of them). I read the `zenity` returns the option as text (e.g. "Display users") a not as tag (as is in `whiptail`), but still do not understand the `FALSE` option prefix.
2. Also in case of `radiolist` in `zenity`, I cannot select the options by labels, but only by the radio buttons (which is not that convenient), is there a command flag to enable to select `radiolist` option by its label ? It would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is before every option FALSE in the command

`FALSE` means the radio button is not selected by default. Change it to `TRUE` to pre-select one of the options.

> I cannot select the options by labels, but only by the radio buttons

I'm not sure if this is possible. I found [this very old bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/1033869) without any answers so I'd assume it is not possible with zenity.

Comment: dik............